# How to handle many-to-many relationships in a single sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

I've been running SQL calls all morning, without any luck on getting the correct kind of data that I want to return.  I did a few searches and found some information on Joining 2 tables, but nothing that pulls from a table, that pulls from a table.  This can sound confusing by wording so I crafted a diagram of the sort of information I'm looking to get.

[image]

I have tried things like,

```
select * from Users 
left join UserLibs on UserLibs.userId = Users.UserId
WHERE Users.username='testname'
```

That however doesn't give me the library name.

So then I tired to join the column with another table and column.

```
select * from users
left join UserLibs on userLibs.userId = Users.UserId AND left join Libraries on  UserLibs.libraryId = Libraries.libraryName
where Users.username='test';
```

Which also didn't produce results, just errors.  Any help with this would be awesome.

### UPDATE

I just wanted to add my final solution that worked for my situation.

```
SELECT Users.userId, Users.username, Users.editLibraries, Users.editAnnouncements, Users.editServices, 
   Users.editNormalHours, Users.editSpecialHours, Users.editUsers, Users.editSemesters, 
   Libraries.libraryName, LibraryDepartment.departmentName
    FROM Users
    LEFT JOIN UserLibs on Users.userId = UserLibs.userId
    LEFT JOIN Libraries on UserLibs.libraryId = Libraries.id
    LEFT JOIN UserDepts on Users.userId = UserDepts.userId
    LEFT JOIN LibraryDepartment on UserDepts.departmentId = LibraryDepartment.ldId
    WHERE Users.username='testname';
```

Comment: `and left join` is flat-out illegal. but that's what you have to do, exactly as it is in your diagram.` select from  `users`, join -> userlibs, join -> libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use AND to perform multiple joins. You just just keep joining tables. You can join as many you like. For example:

```
select *
from users
left join userlibs
on users.userid=userlibs.userid
left join libraries
on userlibs.libraryid=libraries.libraryid
where username='test';
```

Comment: Won't all of the returned rows have the same identical user information in them?

Comment: @nickb No. If username 'test' is mapped to libraryid 6 which is "Main" and libraryid 10 which is "Remote", you will get two records, one for each mapping.

Comment: Right, and in one row, you'll have all of the data for username test, plus the info 6, Main. Then, in the next row, you'll have all of the data for username test, plus the info 10, Remote.

Comment: @kainaw this is working perfectly.  I can't accept the answer yet, but its exactly what I was trying to do.  For some reason I thought in between each additional join I had to have an AND.

The only issue would be that library and department ids are now in there 2 times.

Comment: Correct. The data from table users does not change, but the data for table libraries and userlibs does change. So, the rows don't have identical information, but there will be columns that have identical information. To avoid that, you cannot ask for multiple rows per user (because users have multiple libraries).